# Python/Pygame: Placing text in a specific location

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.4

In my code, I am trying to place a text box in a specific location.

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600), 0, 32) #Set the window to 1000x600

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

text = font.render('Start', True, BLACK)
textRect = text.get_rect()
```

What does the last line do, and how can I modify this code so that the text is placed at a specific (x,y) coordinate?

Comment: A downvote is usually associated with its reason.

Comment: What do you mean by "...modify this code so that the code is placed..."? Did you mean to say something else instead of "code" twice?

Comment: Yes, I meant `so that the TEXT is placed...` lol thanks for catching that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It get the rectangle associated with the rendered surface, change the location like so:

```
textRect.center = (center_x, center_y) # set center to (x, y) coordinates
```

Also, be sure that you are updating the screen and drawing the surface in your game loop:

```
while True:
    pygame.display.flip()
    screen.blit(text, textRect)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```